# Using different Java source version when running Maven2 build

Tags: java, maven-2

I'm attempting to run my Maven build using the usual:

```
mvn clean install
```

I'm getting a whole series of errors that read:

```
annotations are not supported in -source 1.3
(use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)
```

How do I use -source 5 when performing the build. My JAVA_HOME is pointing to JDK 1.6.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this to your pom.xml:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source> 
        <target>1.6</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

It is also documented in the [Maven FAQ](http://maven.apache.org/general.html#Compiling-J2SE-5).

For further information take a look at the [Compiler Plugin documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html).

Answer (score 0):

it's in the pom.xml. you should have `<source>1.3</source>` change it to

```
<source>1.6</source>
```